# How To collect values from JSON response using XsuperObject

Tags: delphi, xsuperobject

I want to parse this JSON using xSuperObject:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "edge_followed_by": {
                "count": 29594,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": true,
                    "end_cursor": ""
                },
                "edges": [{
                    "node": {
                        "id": "224289647",
                        "username": "h9a",
                        "full_name": "",
                        "profile_pic_url": "",
                        "is_verified": false,
                        "followed_by_viewer": false,
                        "requested_by_viewer": false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```pascal
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  item, item2 : IMember;
begin
  json := TSuperObject.Create(Memo1.Text);
  for item in json['edges'].AsArray do
  begin
    Memo2.Lines.Add(item.AsObject['node.username'].ToString);
  end;
end;
```

I want to collect all username values from the JSON, but my code raises an AccessViolation.

Comment: Since I went through the extra effort of figuring out your JSON structure (since it was both unformatted *and* incomplete), I've edited it into your question so that nobody else has to. But please, provide things in a way that we can quickly test it in the future. Because now I've wasted my time and had to delete my answer over an unrelated typo. It's not fair when we have to put in more effort than you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to jump straight to the `edges` array without first stepping through its parent elements. The actual location of the array you wish is at `data.user.edge_followed_by.edges`.

It should work more like this...

```
var
  Obj: ISuperObject;
  Arr: ISuperArray;
  Itm: IMember;
begin
  Obj:= SO(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  Arr:= Obj.O['data'].O['user'].O['edge_followed_by'].A['edges'];
  for Itm in Arr do begin
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Itm.AsObject.O['node'].S['username']);
  end;
end;
```